# Problema com CORS em aplicação Reactjs

Tags: node.js, react, api, cors

Verifiquei em outras perguntas porém não encontrei resposta que se enquadra em meu problema.

Tenho uma aplicação ReactJS que está no meu localhost:3000 e preciso fazer um post para minha API que está no meu localhost:4000.

O envio dos dados é bloqueado pelo CORS, mas até então, já fiz outros testes em minha API e tudo está funcionando corretamente. Inclusive consigo fazer a mesma requisição através do insomnia.

CORS API:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-with, Cotent-type, Accept, privatekey')
    next()
}
```

As requisições no app React são através do Axios. Erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: _CORS_ é uma política implementada no seu navegador, programas como o _Insomnia_ não são sujeitos a essas políticas, por isso não você não tem erros ao testar as requisições por esse programa. O seu problema é que no seu middleware, você está concedendo permissões para o header `cotent-type`, não para o `content-type`, erro de sintaxe, faltou o _n_.

Comment: Muito obrigado e desculpe minha ignorância !

Comment: Uma dica: permita o método `OPTIONS` no seu header para permitir que o servidor indique quais métodos são acessíveis a rota.

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde.

Primeiramente tente instalar essa biblioteca cors ela vai ajudar você a trabalhar melhor com CORS

1. npm install cors
2. Importe a dependência

```js
const cors = require("cors")
```

Depois adicione essa linha de código

```js
app.use(cors({
  origin: '*'
}))
```